# When is "no rest for the wicked" used?

Tags: phrases, proverbs

I've stumbled over some dialogue in a textbook, where some people have a chat at work, and at the end, when they get back to their urgent tasks, one character says (emph. mine):

> Well, I'd better let you carry on
>   then. *No rest for the wicked.*

Now, I've found out [where the phrase comes](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/257500.html) from, but I do not quite follow in which context it can be "used for mild comic effect".

Comment: "When is 'no rest for the wicked' used?" [At Cage The Elephant concerts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKtsdZs9LJo).

Comment: There's another version of this expression, used interchangeably and nearly as often: "No rest for the *weary*."  This, in turn, leads to an old favorite joke, in which a large lady is kicked off of the Overland stagecoach because her butt's too big to fit.  As he's escorting her off the stage, the conductor apologizes:  "I'm sorry, ma'am - there's no West for the reary."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's an idiom, generally used when somebody is expressing their belief that they (or someone else) has to work without rest.  'For the wicked' is a somewhat tongue-in-cheek expression implying that the reason the person is having to work is as a punishment for their being wicked, but this meaning is never literally intended.